# Error: file i/o in python

Tags: python, django, linux, file, ubuntu-10.04

My views.py file code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse
#from skey import find_root_tags, count, sorting_list
from search.models import Keywords
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response as rr

def front_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        from skey import find_root_tags, count, sorting_list
        str1 = request.POST['word'] 
        fo = open("/home/pooja/Desktop/xml.txt","r")

        for i in range(count.__len__()):

            file = fo.readline()
            file = file.rstrip('\n')
            find_root_tags(file,str1,i) 

            list.append((file,count[i]))

        sorting_list(list)

        for name, count1 in list:
            s = Keywords(file_name=name,frequency_count=count1)
            s.save()

        fo.close()

        list1 = Keywords.objects.all()
        t = loader.get_template('search/results.html')
        c = RequestContext({'list1':list1,
        })

        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

    else :  
        str1 = ''
        list = []
        template = loader.get_template('search/front_page.html')
        c = RequestContext(request)
        response = template.render(c)
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

the variable "file" that I'm sending in function `find_root_tags(file,str1,i)` has a xml file's name. This file is present on my desktop, and this code is written in views.py file of my django app, so it is unable to open that file. How can I open that file because xml.txt contains similar filenames that are to be read and then opened. In short, how can I send the file argument as:

```
file1 = '/home/pooja/Desktop/<filename>'
```

here `<filename>` equals the value stored in variable `file` and finall able to call it as:

```
find_root_tags(file1, str1, i)
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

clarification :

1) please refer to the variable "file" in which you can see that I'm storing the read content of xml.txt.

2)xml.txt contains xml filenames. The views.py file is the part of django app's which is unable to open these files since they are present on desktop.

3) my question is how to modify and send the file variable containing filename appended with it's absolute path which is:

```
'/home/pooja/Desktop/filename'
```

by doing this it will open the files present on the Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this:**

```
pathh='/home/pooja/Desktop/'      #set the base path       
fo = open("/home/pooja/Desktop/xml.txt")
for i in range(len(count)):     #use len(count)
    file = fo.readline()
    file = file.strip()          #use strip()
    find_root_tags(pathh+file,str1,i) #base path+file
    mylist.append((file,count[i]))   #using 'list' as a variable name is not good
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question, the file `/home/pooja/Desktop/xml.txt` contains file names, one per line, relative to `/home/pooja/Desktop/` and you need to pass the full path name to `find_root_tags`.

In Python, you can use `+` to concatenate strings, so you could do something like the following:

```
files_path = "/home/pooja/Desktop/"

for i in range(len(count)):

    file = fo.readline()
    file = file.rstrip('\n')
    find_root_tags(files_path + file, str1, i) 

    list.append((file,count[i]))
```

#### Asides

First, note that I have replaced your `count.__len__` with `len(count)`. In Python, magic methods, i.e. methods of the form `__xxxx__` are not called directly. They are defined to be called by some other mechanism. For the [**len**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) method, it is called internally when you use the `len()` built-in.

Second, note that if you have less lines in `xml.txt` than `len(count)`, then `fo.readline` will raise an exception once you have read all the lines of your files. The usual way of reading all the lines of a file in Python is:

```
my_file = open("/path/to/file", 'r')
for line in my_file:
    # do something with your line
```

Finally, to make sure your file is closed whatever happens, i.e. even if an exception is raised while you read the file, you can use the [with statement](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.close).

So in your example, you would do something like:

```
files_path = "/home/pooja/Desktop/"
with open("/path/to/file", 'r') as my_file:
    for file in my_file:
        file = file.rstrip('\n')
        find_root_tags(files_path + file, str1, i) 

        list.append((file,count[i]))
```